# How to get the for loop i value after running a sql function in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, for-loop

Below is my code.i need to get the value of 'i' as exactly as i am getting above the

```
'sql.query(Tosql,function(err,res){'
```

line,but i am not getting the same value i am getting 4,4,4,4 in this line

```
console.log(i +'here i am getting the i value as 4');
```

but i need tha above i value?

```
   sql.query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field1` <= '"+value+"'",function(err,rows){



                  if(rows.length >=1){
                    for(i=0;i<=rows.length;i++)
                    {

                      var Tosql = "UPDATE `table1` SET `field2` = '1' WHERE `table1`.`id` = '"+rows[i].id+"';";
                        // it results of totally 4 rows as output for above query
                        console.log(i +'here i am getting the value as 0,1,2,3');


                       sql.query(Tosql,function(err,res){
                       console.log(i +'here i am getting the i value as 4');
                      return
    })

                  }
              }
          });
```

Comment: `sql.query` is **asynchronous** !

Comment: can you say it in brief?i didnt get you?

Comment: sql.query is async, it has a callback, that callback executes **later**, when the outer loop has completed, and when the outer loop has completed `i` is set to `4`, as that's the last number it was set to.

Comment: can you show it with code how to do it?